# Does Phonegap add GUI customizations per device?

Tags: cordova

If I have a web app (GUI in HTML/CSS, behaviour in Javascript) which is intended for a few differing handset, does Phonegap apply customization of the GUI depending upon the target device?
i.e. can it turn a generic GUI layout into one that conforms to a device's (i.e. iOS) GUI look and feel, or does the HTML/CSS have to be written specifically for each target handset to customize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PhoneGap wont do that for you. If you need custom GUI stuff depending on the device your App runs on, you have to implement it yourself.